# Storing queue priority in database without making an obscene number of queries?

Tags: mysql, database, queue, business-logic

I am designing a queuing system. Every worker will be performing an action every second; potentially for years at a time.

I would like to be able to shift the priority/order in the database on the fly...but supposing I have 10,000 tasks in the queue (very possible), and I shift the 10,000th one to the first place, I now have to affect all 10,000 rows and shift their numerical priority assignment by 1.

Obviously this could get intense on the machines.

Is there a better way to do this either in the database (MySQL) or in my business logic? (PHP, if it matters)

Comment: It's not obvious to me

Comment: Leave gaps, depending on the number of times you expect to need to change a priority. For example, start with 10,20,30,..., then if you need to bump an entry, set it to 9: if 9 is already there, to 8, etc.

Comment: Why do you need to shift 10k rows? You can use UNSIGNED. And do the priority need to be unique?

Comment: @Paul, it needs to be unique withing the scope of another column. IE, worker scrope.